# Entity Framework / MVC Remove Item from Collection

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

What are some ways I can delete an item from a collection? (I am using MVC 4 and EF.)

As an example:

```
public class Birthday
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Gift> Gifts { get; set; }
}

public class Gift
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) to create a dynamic list of Gifts.

The example is shows how to "Delete" a row.  This will delete the row from the page and the correct Gifts are sent to the controller.

When I update the Birthday / Gifts everything new is updated properly, but anything deleted is still there.

So my question is what are some preferred ways to remove Gifts?

Two ways I've thought of already:

1. Get a Birthday from the DB and compare the Gifts removing as needed.  I don't love this idea because it seems heavy handed.
2. Use WebApi / Ajax and delete the Gift from the list and the DB when the user pushes the delete link. I like this better than #1 but does this put too much business logic in the presentation layer?

I'm guessing that other people have had this similar problem and have a clever solution I haven't thought of yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a Gifts api controller. 
Let it have a Delete method accepting an Id of whatever type your Id is.
And do something like this in it:

```
public class GiftsController: ApiController
{
     public void Delete(Guid Id)
     {
           var context = new MyContext();
           var giftToDelete = context.Gifts.FirstOrDefault(g=> g.Id == Id);
           if(giftToDelete != null)
           {
                 context.Gifts.Remove(giftToDelete);
                 context.SaveChanges();
           }
     }
}
```

Make sure you make a DELETE request to this api in your JS delete function.
You may also replace the body of this method with some `Service.DeleteGift(Id)` if you're too concerned about doing things in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        private List<string> list = new List<string>{"Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4","Item5"};

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public List<string> DeleteItem(int id)
        {
            list.Remove(list.Find((i => i.ToString().Contains(id.ToString()))));
            return list;
        }
    }
```